# Grails UrlMappings alphanumeric id

Tags: url, grails, controller, mapping, url-mapping

I managed to have a string id domain with assigned generator, so the url to show/edit is `/controller/action/alphanumeric_id`.

It worked fine till I do vulnerabilities tests, so I found a problem when the id contain slashes (and backslash) even when encoded with %2F (and %5C) the browser gives 400 Bad Request error.

My mapping is the default one `/$controller/$action?/$id?` and I watched with a validator into the constraints to see what is going on, but the request not even arrive there when containing these characters.

If I access `/controller/action/?id=alphanumeric_id` all goes well, but I wonder if there is no way to continue using default short url.

**EDIT:**

- Create a new grails application (mine is version 2.1.3);
- Create a controller;
- In any action do `println params.id`, if you want you can do so in UrlMapping too;
- Try to access your controller by `/appname/controller/action/abc`, it goes fine;
- Now try `/appname/controller/action/a%2Fbc` or `/appname/controller/action/a%5Cbc`, it gives 400 Bad Request;
- Other combinations with `%00` upto `%FF` should work as well, but not all of them does, by the way, `%00` also do not work.

**BUGGED COMBINATIONS:** `%00` `%2F` `%5C`

Comment: You could try a mapping of: `/$controller/$action?/$id**?` Maybe make it more specific for only the controllers/actions that require this url format?

Comment: @tim_yates Sorry, do not worked, but that is the idea.

Comment: What version of grails are you on? Maybe [you're hitting this](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6587)?

Comment: 2.1.3, but I didn't have problem with spaces yet.